# Python: Unit test case shows no error if login does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, unit-testing, python-unittest

**Setup**

I use the following packages in addition to Python 3.7:
Testcore (A special Package with paramiko inside!), Pyserial

```
import testcore
from testcore.control.ssh import SSH
import unittest
from test import support
import logging
import os


def setUp(self):

    self.s = testcore.control.ssh.SSH(host='172.23.xx.xxx',
                                  username='admin', password='admin', type_of_dut='ecos')
    logger.info('self.s = testcore.control.ssh.SSH')
    self.s.query_interactive=True


    if self.s.login():
        logger.info('login')
        q = self.s.query('account')
        logger.info('account')
        self.assertIsNotNone(q, 'missing answer')
        self.assertEqual('\r\n', q, 'unexpected result')
        logger.info('missing answer')
        logger.info('unexpected result')

        # switch to prompt account

        q=self.s.query('enforce-Password-Rules yes')
        logger.info('enforce-Password-Rules yes')
        q=self.s.query('exit')
        logger.info('exit')

def tearDown(self):
    self.s.close()
```

**Information:**

In my structure put on various users on a hardware switch. In a second test, I check if the newly created user can log in.

According to Log, he can also log in, which is also logged accordingly.

In my structure is not acted what should happen if the test case fails, actually the test case would not have to log in when he logs in that he can not connect. Unfortunately, he writes this only in a log and the test case is still positive.

**Create User**

```
    def test_create_user_1(self):
    logger_true.info('test_create_user_1')
    if self.s.loggedin:
        logger.info('self.s.loggedin')
        q = self.s.query('account')
        logger.info('account')
        self.assertIsNotNone(q, 'missing answer')
        self.assertEqual('\r\n', q, 'unexpected result')
        logger.info('missing answer')
        logger.info('unexpected result')

        # switch to prompt account

        q = self.s.query('add 1 testuser_P1 testuser_P1')
        logger.info('add 1 testuser_P1 testuser_P1')
        q = self.s.query('exit')
        self.assertIsNotNone(q, 'missing answer')
        self.assertEqual('\r\n', q, 'unexpected result')
        logger.info('missing answer')
        logger.info('unexpected result')

        q = self.s.query('logout')
        logger.info('logout')

        import time
        print('Wait')
        time.sleep(2)
        print('True')
        logger_true.info('True')
        self.s.close()
```

The user is demonstrably created (if one looks at the switch over command Show the user list). So far, so everything is positive and this test case is passed.

In the next step, I want to make a login that checks whether the user can log in on the prompt.

**Problem:**

If I remove the password for a negative test from the SSH connection at self.s = testcore.control.ssh.SSH (host = '172.xx.xx.xxx', username = 'testuser_P1', password = 'testuser_P1'), the test will run anyway through. The test is therefore not shown as negative.

Any Idea to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was **fixed by me.**
I have over

self.s.login ()
         self.assertEqual (self.s.loggedin, False)

In accordance with an assert, I do not log in as a false one. This is logged over another logfile.

```
    def test_try_login2(self):
    logger_true.info('test_try_login1')
    self.s.close()
    self.s = testcore.control.ssh.SSH(host='172.23.xxx.xxx',username='testuser_P2', password='testuser_P2')
    self.s.query_interactive = True

    self.s.login()
    self.assertEqual(self.s.loggedin, False)
    print('True')
    logger_true.info('True')
    self.s.close()
```